# I'm implementing google sign in using flutter and firestore. On click, user should should sign in with google and navigate user to a create user page

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have a google_sign_in button which when clicked should present the google sign in then the user should be redirected to a CreateAccountPage. The page has an input and a submit button. When the user submits their preferred username, the google account data together with the created username should be stored as a document in users collection cloud firestore database and the user redirected to another page, say TimelinePage.

Below is my home.dart file:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:musagram/pages/activity_feed.dart';
import 'package:musagram/pages/create_account.dart';
import 'package:musagram/pages/profile.dart';
import 'package:musagram/pages/search.dart';
import 'package:musagram/pages/timeline.dart';
import 'package:musagram/pages/upload.dart';

final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final usersRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
final DateTime timestamp = DateTime.now();

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool isAuth = false;
  PageController pageController;
  int pageIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    pageController = PageController();
    // Detects when user signed in
    googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((account) {
      handleSignIn(account);
    }, onError: (err) {
      print('Error signing in: $err');
    });
    // Reauthenticate user when app is opened
    googleSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).then((account) {
      handleSignIn(account);
    }).catchError((err) {
      print('Error signing in: $err');
    });
  }

  handleSignIn(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    if (account != null) {
      createUserInFirestore();
      setState(() {
        isAuth = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isAuth = false;
      });
    }
  }

  createUserInFirestore() async {
    // 1) check if user exists in users collection in database (according to their id)
    final GoogleSignInAccount user = googleSignIn.currentUser;
    final DocumentSnapshot doc = await usersRef.doc(user.id).get();

    if (!doc.exists) {
      // 2) if the user doesn't exist, then we want to take them to the create account page
      final username = await Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccount()));

      // 3) get username from create account, use it to make new user document in users collection
      usersRef.doc(user.id).set({
        "id": user.id,
        "username": username,
        "photoUrl": user.photoUrl,
        "email": user.email,
        "displayName": user.displayName,
        "bio": "",
        "timestamp": timestamp
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    pageController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  login() {
    googleSignIn.signIn();
  }

  logout() {
    googleSignIn.signOut();
  }

  onPageChanged(int pageIndex) {
    setState(() {
      this.pageIndex = pageIndex;
    });
  }

  onTap(int pageIndex) {
    pageController.animateToPage(
      pageIndex,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
    );
  }

  Scaffold buildAuthScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: PageView(
        children: <Widget>[
          // Timeline(),
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Logout'),
            onPressed: logout,
          ),
          ActivityFeed(),
          Upload(),
          Search(),
          Profile(),
        ],
        controller: pageController,
        onPageChanged: onPageChanged,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: CupertinoTabBar(
          currentIndex: pageIndex,
          onTap: onTap,
          activeColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.whatshot)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.notifications_active)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.photo_camera,
                size: 35.0,
              ),
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle)),
          ]),
    );
    // return RaisedButton(
    //   child: Text('Logout'),
    //   onPressed: logout,
    // );
  }

  Scaffold buildUnAuthScreen() {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            colors: [
              Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ],
          ),
        ),
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'MusaGram',
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "Signatra",
                fontSize: 90.0,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            GestureDetector(
              onTap: login,
              child: Container(
                width: 260.0,
                height: 60.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: AssetImage(
                      'assets/images/google_signin_button.png',
                    ),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isAuth ? buildAuthScreen() : buildUnAuthScreen();
  }
}
```

And here's the create_account.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:musagram/widgets/header.dart';

class CreateAccount extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CreateAccountState createState() => _CreateAccountState();
}

class _CreateAccountState extends State<CreateAccount> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String username;

  submit() {
    _formKey.currentState.save();
    Navigator.pop(context, username);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext parentContext) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: header(context, titleText: "Set up your profile"),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Create a username",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        onSaved: (val) => username = val,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: "Username",
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
                          hintText: "Must be at least 3 characters",
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: submit,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 50.0,
                    width: 350.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7.0),
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                      "Submit",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 15.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Google signin works perfectly but I'm not being redirected to the create_account page where I'm supposed to input my preferred username. The user data is also not posted in cloud firestore database

Comment: you are doing to much task in your init() method. that's not issue. but I think you should avoid this. rather You will create a new class which will handle your database and authentication methods. and you can call sign in method on click of button like login with google. and then from that method on successful login you can navigate to new page

Answer (score 1):

method of google sign in looks like this. It will first authenticate the user then it will check is users data present on the firestore. if it's present data will not be overridden and else data will be added.
also at the end you can navigate to your `createAccountPage`.  and you can pass the required values to the constructor. directly `map` of data or `values`.

```
     Future<UserCredential> signInWithGoogle() async {
    //first trigger authentication
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
    //obtain the auth details
    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
        await googleUser.authentication;
    //create a new credentials
    final GoogleAuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken, idToken: googleAuth.idToken);
    //saving the user data to shared preferences
    SharedPrefsHelper _sharedpref = new SharedPrefsHelper();

    // // sign in method
    try {
      UserCredential firebaseUser =
          await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);
      if (firebaseUser != null) {
        // Check is already sign up
        final QuerySnapshot result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .where('id', isEqualTo: firebaseUser.user.uid)
            .get();
   
//userdata to update at firebase 
//passing this via constructor to the next page

Map<String, dynamic> userdata =  {
              'useremail': firebaseUser.user.email,
              'displayname': firebaseUser.user.displayName,
              'photoUrl': firebaseUser.user.photoURL,
              'userid': firebaseUser.user.uid,
            };


// navigate . if you don't have context here you can pass this as a paramater to the 
method. no issue if you call inside build or init
   

 //userdata is map. just for handling easily
    //you can also create simple variables and pass each value to them.
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, CreateUserAccount(userdata));
        }
      
      return firebaseUser;
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```

**Inside the CreateUserAccount**

```
class CreateUserAccount extends StatefulWidget {
  final Map<String, dynamic> userdata;
  CreateUserAccount(this.userdata);
  @override
  CreateUserAccountState createState() => CreateUserAccountState();
}

class CreateUserAccountState extends State<CreateUserAccount> {
  TextEditingController _textController = new TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 20),
            child: TextField(
              controller: _textController,
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async{
//get the username from textfield
//and update data to firebase
      widget.userdata['username'] = _textController.text;
            await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('users')
                  .doc(widget.userdata['userId'])
                  .set(
                    widget.userdata,
                    SetOptions(merge: true),
                  );
Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => TimeLinePage());
            },
            child: Text("submit"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Inside the `CreateUserAccount` we simply added the username in map and added record in firebase. Then you can navigate to the timeline after this.